# Passing data in Apex Pages

Tags: html, sql, oracle-apex

I want to pass the data from one page (a form) to another without actually adding the data to the database. I will use the 'next' button to pass the values (data) and 'submit' button to insert all the details from previous pages to the database. Does anyone know how can I achieve this in Oracle Apex Pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [apex collections](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/apex_collection.htm#AEAPI531).

In the first page create a process assigned to your NEXT button where you save your form data to the collection, just like in the example above:

```
BEGIN
    apex_collection.create_or_truncate_collection(p_collection_name => 'FORM_DATA');

    apex_collection.add_member( p_collection_name => 'FORM_DATA'
                              , p_c001            => :P1_ITEM1
                              , p_c002            => :P1_ITEM2
                              , p_c003            => :P1_ITEM3
                              , p_c004            => :P1_ITEM4
                              , p_c005            => :P1_ITEM5      
                              );

    END LOOP;
END;
```

You can also use p_n001 - p_n005 for numbers and p_d001 - p_d005 for dates as you can read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/apex_collection.htm#AEAPI690)

In the second page in will need to create a custom process to save your data to DB where you'll need to read the data from the collection, just like the example above:

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO my_table (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10)
    SELECT c001
    ,      c002
    ,      c003
    ,      c004
    ,      c005
   -- 2nd page form items
    ,      :P2_ITEM1
    ,      :P2_ITEM2
    ,      :P2_ITEM3
    ,      :P2_ITEM4
    ,      :P2_ITEM5
      FROM apex_collections
     WHERE collection_name = 'FORM_DATA'; -- collection name must be uppercase
END;
```